# Issues with plotting a time series in ggplot, with legends (Stock prices)

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, time-series, stock

I am trying to plot a stock prices with indicators, however I cannot find out how to add labels to the plot. I think I am having trouble understanding how ggplot works with time series. I have seen others create new column with all of the data but I do not see how that will apply here. I originally wanted to plot the closing price along with the 50 and 200 day moving averages, and a label to show Accordingly.

here is the data and plot without the labels. Any resources on learning more about ggplot are also welcomed.

```
structure(c(3.320236, 3.300589, 3.483955, 3.588736, 3.418468, 
3.497053, 3.549443, 3.582187, 3.601834, 3.588736, 1803600, 2480600, 
2608100, 2315800, 3706400, 2648200, 1851400, 1297000, 2230600, 
1667900, 4.04544857999999, 4.01964633999999, 4.00091679999999, 
3.98559263999999, 3.96987555999999, 3.95442041999999, 3.94407331999999, 
3.93791745999999, 3.92586769999999, 3.91892597999999, 4.80337260999993, 
4.79541582999993, 4.78650947499993, 4.77812702499993, 4.76981006499993, 
4.76195151999993, 4.75271772499993, 4.74482643499993, 4.73775374499993, 
4.72956775999993, 169569500, 167088900, 169697000, 172012800, 
168306400, 170954600, 172806000, 174103000, 176333600, 174665700, 
3.32023599999963, 3.30058899999973, 3.48395499999974, 3.58873599999971, 
3.41846799999982, 3.49705299999975, 3.54944299999964, 3.58218699999948, 
3.6018339999997, 3.5887359999996), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1546387200, 
1546473600, 1546560000, 1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 
1547164800, 1547424000, 1547510400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SPWR.Close", "SPWR.Volume", "SMA", 
"SMA.1", "obv", "VWAP")))
```

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = Price)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = SPWR.Close)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SMA), col = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = SMA.1), col = "blue")
```

Comment: Please add the `dput(yourdata)` correctly the one included has typoes!

Comment: There's actually a nice time series method implemented, try `plot(df)` (`library(xts)` must be loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to go it to convert your TS to a dataframe and convert the rownames to a new column. Then rearrange the data to plot it in an concise way

```
# needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# your dummy data
df <- structure(c(3.320236, 3.300589, 3.483955, 3.588736, 3.418468, 
              3.497053, 3.549443, 3.582187, 3.601834, 3.588736, 1803600, 2480600, 
              2608100, 2315800, 3706400, 2648200, 1851400, 1297000, 2230600, 
              1667900, 4.04544857999999, 4.01964633999999, 4.00091679999999, 
              3.98559263999999, 3.96987555999999, 3.95442041999999, 3.94407331999999, 
              3.93791745999999, 3.92586769999999, 3.91892597999999, 4.80337260999993, 
              4.79541582999993, 4.78650947499993, 4.77812702499993, 4.76981006499993, 
              4.76195151999993, 4.75271772499993, 4.74482643499993, 4.73775374499993, 
              4.72956775999993, 169569500, 167088900, 169697000, 172012800, 
              168306400, 170954600, 172806000, 174103000, 176333600, 174665700, 
              3.32023599999963, 3.30058899999973, 3.48395499999974, 3.58873599999971, 
              3.41846799999982, 3.49705299999975, 3.54944299999964, 3.58218699999948, 
              3.6018339999997, 3.5887359999996), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1546387200, 1546473600, 1546560000, 1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 1547164800, 1547424000, 1547510400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SPWR.Close", "SPWR.Volume", "SMA", "SMA.1", "obv", "VWAP"))) 

# convert to df
df1 <- as.data.frame(df)
# rownames (dates) to a new column
df1$DATE <- rownames(df1)

df1 %>% 
  # get data in a better format to print
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-DATE, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% 
  # fitler the variable you want to print
  dplyr::filter(Variable %in% c("SPWR.Close", "SMA", "SMA.1")) %>% 
  # plot using the group feature of ggplot2
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = DATE, y = Values, group = Variable, color = Variable)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works well, however what if I wanted to make one of the plots as a scatter using the `geom_point` function? or suppose I wanted to plot the SPWR.volume as a bar chart on the bottom?

Comment: the easy way out would be to not filter for any variable and then use facet_wrap(~Variable, scales = "free") after the geom_line() call (with a + between them) - This way you will have 4 separate line charts, one for each variable and each with its own scale. Everything else is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1):

You have an xts/zoo series but the associated library call is missing from the question.  zoo has its own plot methods for classic graphics (plot.zoo), lattice (xyplot.zoo) and ggplot2 (autoplot.zoo).

We illustrate each below using points for the close, histogram bars for the volume and lines for all other columns using 3 panels with the second panel for volume, the third for OBV and all other columns plotted in the first panel.

**1) plot.zoo** Using plot.zoo (we show autoplot.zoo at the end) the arguments screen, col and type have one element per column specifying the panel number (or label) via screen=, color via col= and type (p = point, l = line, h = histogram) via type= for that column.  In legend we specify the position in first argument, legend text in second argument, color via col=, point type for columns drawn as points (20 = filled in point) via pch=, the line type for columns drawn as lines (1 = solid line) via lty=, width for lines via lwd=, size for points via pt.cex=, size for text via cex=, clipping (TRUE = suppress clipping) via xpd= and border (n = no border around legend) via bty=.

```
library(xts)

plot(transform(as.zoo(x), 
       SPWR.Volume = SPWR.Volume / 1000,
       obv  = obv / 1000000),
  main = "SPWR",
  ylab = c("Price", "Volume", "OBV"),
  screen = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1), 
  col = c("black", "blue", "green", "red", "black", "purple"),
  type = c("p", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l"),
  lwd = 2,
  heights = c(4, 1, 1)
)
legend("topleft", c("SMA", "SMA.1", "VWAP", "Close"), 
  col = c("green", "red", "purple", "black"), 
  pch = c(NA, NA, NA, 20), lty = c(1, 1, 1, NA),
  lwd = 2, pt.cex = 1.2, cex = 0.7, xpd = TRUE, bty = "n")
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) xyplot.zoo**  xyplot.zoo uses lattice graphics.  The call is somewhat similar to plot.zoo.

```
library(lattice)
library(xts)

xyplot(transform(as.zoo(x),
                 SPWR.Volume = SPWR.Volume / 1000,
                 obv  = obv / 1000000),
  main = "SPWR",
  ylab = c("Price", "Volume", "OBV"),
  screen = c("Price", "Volume", "Price", "Price", "OBV", "Price"),
  col = c("black", "blue", "green", "red", "black", "purple"),
  type = list("p", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l"),
  lwd = 2,
  par.settings = list(layout.heights = list(panel = c(4, 1, 1)/6)),
  key = list(corner = c(0.05, 0.9),
    lines = list(col = c("green", "red", "purple")),
    text = list(c("SMA", "SMA.1", "VWAP"), cex = 0.7)
  )
)
```

[image: screenshot]

**3) autoplot.zoo** It is fairly complex with ggplot2 but we can do it by creating 3 separate plots and then combining them using cowplot.

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

xx <- transform(as.zoo(x), 
  SPWR.Volume = SPWR.Volume / 1000,
  obv  = obv / 1000000)
p1 <- autoplot(xx$SPWR.Close, geom = "point") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = VWAP, col = "A"), x) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SMA, col = "B"), x) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = SMA.1, col = "C"), x) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", 
    values = c(A = "purple", B = "green", C = "red"), 
    labels = c(A = "VWAP", B = "SMA", C = "SMA.1")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.73), 
    plot.margin = margin(1, 1, -0.5, 1, "cm"),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("SPWR") +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Price")
p2 <- autoplot(xx$SPWR.Volume, fill = "Volume", geom = "col") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "blue") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(-0.5, 1, -0.5, 1, "cm")) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Volume")
p3 <- autoplot(xx$obv) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(-0.5, 1, 1, 1, "cm")) +
  ylab("OBV")
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, align = "v", rel_heights = c(4, 1, 1), ncol = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]